# invisible link is chrome, firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm not a student of computer or anything related to computer. I'm a student of statistics.

Here's a link of a webpage: http://www.isical.ac.in/~deanweb/FinalResult2015/ISIfinalresultlist2015.html

In this link everyone is seeing six links in their computers:

1. MS in Library and Information Science
2. PG Diploma in Computer Applications
3. JRF in QE [ Kolkata]
4. B.Math.
5. B.Stat.
6. M.Math.

but I don't see the sixth option. i.e. the last option 'M.Math.' why is this happening ? I've tried Chrome, Firefox and IE. the latest versions. all the browsers are showing only 5 options. It's weird.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming, but rather debugging help with someone elses code. It is unlikely to help any future visitors either.

Comment: If you are having trouble viewing someone elses page, why not contact their site administrator and ask them about it?

Comment: I see **eight** links in Chrome - "MS in Library and Information Science,
PG Diploma in Computer Applications, JRF in QE [Kolkata], B.Math., B.Stat., M.Math., JRF in Computer Science, MS (QMS)", but 2 hours ago I noted seeing only 6. The site operators might be making updates.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have:

**JRF in QE [ Kolkata]**

where

- **JRF in QE** is colored blue and is text
- **[** is link to PGDCAFINALLIST2015.pdf
- **Kolkata** is link to JRFECOFINALLIST2015.pdf
- **]** is link to PGDCAFINALLIST2015.pdf

There are more of these kind of problems. If this is a static page and not populated by database, then just recreate the content.

Comment: exactly . i see as you have written. but i don't see the last option. the 6th option. and this page is not created by me. but i want visit the link that is currently invisible to me and some more links are to come up soon. i need to visit them. how to fix it ? i'm not the creator of the page.

Comment: It seems that your browser has cache'd the page. Press "Ctrl+F5" or do a page reload. The 6th link is : http://www.isical.ac.in/~deanweb/FinalResult2015/MMATHTFINALLIST15.pdf

Comment: i just formatted my computer and then pressed ctrl+f5 it's working fine now. i think it was due to some virus....:/ anyway , thanks a lot for your help.